# access websites with custom https port via socks proxy

Tags: google-chrome, ssh, putty, https, socks-proxy

I use a socks4 proxy in chrome (ssh tunnel via putty listens on localhost:60000) which works fine for all websites with the default http ports 80 and 443. What does NOT work is accessing websites over a custom port, especially tested for https. Example:

```
https://google.com       # works via socks4 proxy
https://example.com:8443 # does not work via socks4 proxy
      Chrome says: "ERR_CONNECTION_RESET"
```

When I switch to another proxy (http, not socks) or use the direct connection it works like a charm. Same for FF, btw. Proxy settings in chrome are configured with [ProxySwitchySharp](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/proxy-switchysharp/dpplabbmogkhghncfbfdeeokoefdjegm)

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: what about `socks5`? It works?

Comment: No, does not work.